# Why does ant Manifest task split long main class name?

Tags: java, jar, mainclass

The following is my Ant build file contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="testant"
         basedir=".">
  <property file="build.properties" />
  <target name="manifest">
    <tstamp />
    <manifest mode="update"
              file="manifest.mf">
      <attribute name="Built-By"
                 value="${user.name}" />
      <section name="common">
        <attribute name="Specification-Title"
                   value="${ant.project.name}" />
        <attribute name="Specification-Version"
                   value="1.0.0" />
        <attribute name="Specification-Vendor"
                   value="" />
        <attribute name="Implementation-Title"
                   value="" />
        <attribute name="Implementation-Version"
                   value="${TODAY}" />
        <attribute name="Implementation-Vendor"
                   value="" />
      </section>
      <attribute name="Main-Class"
                 value="${main.class}" />
    </manifest>
  </target>
</project>
```

The following is my build.properties.

```
packages=com.javacodegeeks.patterns.strategypattern.*
main.class=com.javacodegeeks.patterns.strategypattern.TestStrategyPattern
```

The following is my output manifest.mf.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.10.6
Created-By: 10.0.2+13 (Oracle Corporation)
Built-By: root
Main-Class: com.javacodegeeks.patterns.strategypattern.TestStrategyPat
 tern

Name: common
Specification-Title: testant
Specification-Version: 1.0.0
Specification-Vendor: 
Implementation-Title: 
Implementation-Version: July 7 2019
Implementation-Vendor:
```

Why are there spaces generated in the main-class name?

It doesn't affect generating the jar file using either the ant  task or the jar command.

The executable jar also works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

[According to the JAR specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html),

> - Line length:
>
>   - No line may be longer than 72 bytes (not characters), in its UTF8-encoded form. If a value would make the initial line longer than this, it should be continued on extra lines (each starting with a single SPACE).

Some tooling seems to disregard this requirement, but Ant is strict about it. Your line is wrapped at 70 characters plus presumably `\r\n`.

Comment: Thanks. I just found a duplicate here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33143460/does-the-jar-manifest-mf-max-line-length-of-72-include-the-eol-bytes question.